# Apache Hive regexp_extract UDF

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am coming across a piece of code in Apache Hive like regexp_extract(input, '[0-9]*', 0), Can someone please explain to me what this code does? Thanks

Answer (score 21):

From [the Hive manual DDL](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF), it returns the string extracted using the pattern. e.g. `regexp_extract('foothebar', 'foo(.*?)(bar)', 2)` returns `bar`.

The `index` parameter is the capture group, which is an integer that can take the following values:

- 0: the entire match, in my example it would be `foothebar`
- 1: the first group, in my example it would be `the`
- 2: the second group, in my example it would be `bar`
- n: the nth group. If n is bigger than the actual number of groups defined in your regexp, your Hive query will fail.

In your example, `regexp_extract(input, '[0-9]*', 0)`, your are looking for the whole match for your column identified by `input` and starting with a numerical value.

Here are a few examples:

- `regexp_extract('9eleven', '[0-9]*', 0)` -> returns `9`
- `regexp_extract('9eleven', '[0-9]*', 1)` -> query fails
- `regexp_extract('911test', '[0-9]*', 0)` -> returns `911`
- `regexp_extract('911test', '[0-9]*', 1)` -> query fails
- `regexp_extract('eleven', '[0-9]*', 0)` -> returns empty string
- `regexp_extract('test911', '[0-9]*', 0)` -> returns empty string

Comment: does it mean that regexp_extract(input, '[0-9]*', 0) will only match input starts with a numerical value? Thanks. Can you please give out some examples?

Comment: @user1653240 I added some examples in the answer.

Comment: so to generalize, the function with return non-empty string if the input starts with one or more integers?

Comment: Is there a way to get "55" and "911" using the same pattern `[0-9]*` ie `regexp_extract('55test911', '[0-9]*', X)`? It should work using a global identifier (with php for example) but how to do so with hive ? I know I could use another pattern, but I'm wondering about the solution of this specific case :-)

Answer (score 3):

The answer above is partially incorrect. `regexp_extract('test911', '[0-9]*', 0)` will certainly return 911. We never specify the start of the string before `[0-9]*`

Comment: Please put it as a comment

Comment: On our hive system `select  regexp_extract('test911', '[0-9]*', 0);` returns the empty string. This is not really surprising as the regexp_extract method is based on the concept of capturing groups, and if there are none defaults to the first substring match of the given regex. The regex example `'[0-9]*'` here is zero or more digits, and that regex is matched right at the beginning of the string with zero digits. For all the gory details look at the source code https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/udf/UDFRegExpExtract.java

Answer (score -1):

The regular expression `regexp_extract(input, '[0-9]*', 0)` will give all starting digits in the input string.

eg,

```
select regexp_extract('442323test41234', '[0-9]*', 0) ==> 442323
select regexp_extract('44test41234', '[0-9]*', 0) ==> 44
select regexp_extract('test41234', '[0-9]*', 0) ==> 1
```

But it's not the best way to extract starting numbers. The below is more readable format:

```
select regexp_extract(input, '^([0-9]+).*?$', 1)
```

The above regular expression says, list all the digits that are starting in the string and ignore the rest.

Comment: regexp_extract does not return "starting matches", it uses Java's find() method to look for substrings, no matter where they occur. It does however begin this search at the beginning of the input string, maybe that's where the confusion arises. Your more readable format is different from the others because it uses "+" and hence looks for one or more digits, while the other regex's use "*" and look for zero or more digits. Finally, the example `select regexp_extract('test41234', '[0-9]*', 0)` returns the empty string and not '1', see my comment to the previous answer.